# How can I delete last item on the list in realtime database in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building simple todo app in Javascript and I use firebase's realtime database as my database to store tasks for each user. Retrieving and writing data works fine but the problem shows up when I want to delete something from the list. Specifically I want to delete last item when I click button.

This is how my database looks like:

[image: Tasks database]

And here's code for retrieving data:

```
db.on('child_added', snapshot => {

    let span = document.createElement('span');
    span.setAttribute('class', 'listItem');
    let textNode = document.createTextNode(snapshot.val().name + `\n`);
    span.appendChild(textNode);

    snapshot.forEach(() => {
        if(snapshot.val().uid == user.uid) {
            todoListContent.appendChild(span);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I understand the task, but what's the problem you're having with implementing it?

Comment: I've read in the official docs that you have to you use remove function, but I don't know what reference should I use to delete tasks properly.

Answer (score 0):

To delete a node from the database, you need to know the full path of that node. This means that you either must store the key of each node, or store some other values that allow you to look up that key.

In your case storing the key seems easiest, by associating it with the `span` you create:

```
db.on('child_added', snapshot => {

    let span = document.createElement('span');
    span.setAttribute('id', snapshot.key); // store the key for later reference
    span.setAttribute('class', 'listItem');
    let textNode = document.createTextNode(snapshot.val().name + `\n`);
    span.appendChild(textNode);

    snapshot.forEach(() => {
        if(snapshot.val().uid == user.uid) {
            todoListContent.appendChild(span);
        }
    });
});
```

Now when the user clicks on the `span` to delete that node, you get the key from its `id` attribute and then can delete the node with:

```
let key = span.id;
 db.child(key).remove();
```